# How to charge my Ubuntu phone's battery off my Ubuntu laptop's battery?

Tags: usb, ubuntu-touch, battery, phone, charging

When I plug my BQ Aquaris Ubuntu phone into my laptop running 14.04.3 LTS and shut down the laptop *while the phone is charging* the phone *keeps charging...*

Once I unplug the phone however, it doesn't charge any more after I plug it back into any of the the USB ports of the shut-down computer.

*How can I continue charging my phone's battery off my laptop's battery?*

<sub>I know: it's a bad idea as it'll drain the laptop battery, but this is an emergency and that's what I need *right now!*  **:P  ;-)**</sub>

Answer (score 12, accepted):

### Easy:

1. Turn on the laptop
2. Go to the BIOS settings (no need to fully boot the computer)
3. Make sure charging external devices during low power states is enabled (if the option is present)

   [image: BIOS Screen]
4. Plug in the phone
5. Shut down the computer.

#### Now the phone will charge off the laptop's battery again!

*If that doesn't work:*

1. boot up the computer fully into Ubuntu and:

   ```
   sudo apt-get install acpitool
   ```
2. Do a:

   ```
   acpitool -w
   ```

   to see the ACPI capable devices
3. Then do:

   ```
   sudo acpitool -W iDevice
   ```

   where `iDevice` is the device you want to switch from `*disabled` to `*enabled`

Comment: Actually this feature is called Connected Standby and that's what allows the magical Wake-On LAN to happen. Some devices are selectively powered. You can install `acpitool` to configure it.

Comment: @AshharHasan: Thank you for the comment: incorporated into answer.