# Is it possible that PC can use phone battery during suspend?

Tags: suspend

I plugged in my phone to recharge using USB recharger. When I went to bed I put my PC to suspend and then when I woke up my phone battery was 0% (even if it was almost full when I left it).

Is it possible that my desktop PC with Ubuntu on it used my phone's battery during suspend?

Comment: I don't think so, I **suspect** that your phone is configured to stay on when connected to usb (which would do it). Regardless, this isn't really an Ubuntu question.

Comment: When you "suspend" the PC, it cuts power to things like USB ports, the display, etc. to save the computer's available power. Your phone will not charge if connected while the computer is suspended. Also, off-topic here.

Comment: Actually @TheBrownOne but suspending just instructs the computer to step into a very low consumption of available power... thus you can actually charge a device connected through the USB port. I  charge my android phone even while my pc is on suspend.... It is also true that the above question is not an Ubuntu question.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to charge my Ubuntu phone's battery off my Ubuntu laptop's battery?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/706641/how-to-charge-my-ubuntu-phones-battery-off-my-ubuntu-laptops-battery)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@Kunok your phone is built to use the pc's energy, not the contrary. So I think your usb cable was not more establishing the connection whereas your phone was draining. If that fails to be the case then you should check your phone charging system. Now, Ubuntu OS cannot be responsible for that right? I mean just be fair... cheers.